# How to capture stdout/stderr with googletest?

Tags: c++, unit-testing, stdout, stderr, googletest

Is it possible to capture the stdout and stderr when using the [googletest](http://code.google.com/p/googletest/) framework?

For example, I would like to call a function that writes errors to the console (stderr).
Now, when calling the function in the tests, I want to assert that no output appears there.

Or, maybe I want to test the error behaviour and want to assert that a certain string gets printed when I (deliberately) produce an error.

Comment: From a design point of view, I would suggest modifying the implementation so that switching to log files be less painful. Using the `ostream` interface would make it easier for example.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

I have used this snippet before to redirect cout calls to a stringstream when testing output. Hopefully it might spark some ideas. I've never used googletest before.

```
// This can be an ofstream as well or any other ostream
std::stringstream buffer;

// Save cout's buffer here
std::streambuf *sbuf = std::cout.rdbuf();

// Redirect cout to our stringstream buffer or any other ostream
std::cout.rdbuf(buffer.rdbuf());

// Use cout as usual
std::cout << "Hello World";

// When done redirect cout to its old self
std::cout.rdbuf(sbuf);
```

Before redirecting back to the original output use your google test to check the output in buffer.

Comment: This doesn't work for googletest since gtest uses printf which goes straight to stdout, circumventing your redirect. But it is a nice solution if you want to intercept the output of  `cout << ...`. I would create a helper class though to automatically restore the original streambuf in the destructor...

Comment: I've added a way one might use this with Google Test barring the scenario commented above.

Answer (score 135):

Googletest offers functions for this:

```
testing::internal::CaptureStdout();
std::cout << "My test";
std::string output = testing::internal::GetCapturedStdout();
```

Comment: probably the simplest possible solution

Comment: This is only available for `stdout`, not `stderr`? There are death tests that capture `stderr`, but in many cases you may not be testing for process termination.

Comment: testing::internal::CaptureStderr() also exists. Is used here for example: https://googletest.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/test/gtest-death-test_test.cc

Comment: the message is still printed on screen? how to suppress that?

Comment: One should know that this is a private API and is therefore not supported. I'd advise against it

Comment: I found this to segfault if called more than once, even in different tests, and therefore worthless.

Comment: This solution won't work if the unit-under-test throws an exception.

Comment: This doesn't work for me. I still get no printout on the screen or in the log.

Comment: @NirFriedman it seems that one has to call `::testing::internal::CaptureStdout()` prior to _each_ capture.

Comment: @NirFriedman true, but do you know why `::testing::internal::CaptureStdout()` needs to be called prior to each capture?

Answer (score 7):

Avoiding having to do this is always a good design idea. If you really want to do it the following works:

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <cassert>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <iostream>

int main() {
   int fd = open("my_file.log", O_WRONLY|O_CREAT|O_TRUNC, 0660);
   assert(fd >= 0);
   int ret = dup2(fd, 1);
   assert(ret >= 0);
   printf("This is stdout now!\n");
   std::cout << "This is C++ iostream cout now!" << std::endl;
   close(fd);
}
```

To use stderr instead of stdout change the second argument to dup2 to be 2. For capturing without going via a file you could use a pipe pair instead.

Answer (score 4):

Rather than do this, use dependency injection to remove the direct use of `std::cout`. In your test code use a mock object of class `std:ostringstream` as a mock object instead of the real `std::cout`.

So instead of this:

```
 void func() {
    ...
    std::cout << "message";
    ...
 }

 int main (int argc, char **argv) {
    ...
    func();
    ...
 }
```

have this:

```
 void func(std::ostream &out) {
    ...
    out << "message";
    ...
 }

 int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    ...
    func(std::cout);
    ...
 }
```

Comment: While this is a good idea in general, it won't work in his case because gtest is an external library (from his viewpoint) and he wants to capture the output of the framework without modifying the source code.

Comment: What if he/she has many functions that prints some error messages or logs? This won't work in that case as adding extra parameter just for capturing a stream is not a good idea. One thing he/she can do is to use global stream object and change/redirect it according to needs. std::cout, std::cerr and std::clog are such global objects. It's better to use std::cout and redirect it to another stream when needed.

Comment: @KeshacSabu if there are many such functions, there are many design faults in the code to be fixed. Fixing them *is* a good idea.

Answer (score 2):

Putting Wgaffa's suggestion (which I like) to a Google Test fixture, one might write:

```
namespace {

    class MyTestFixture : public ::testing::Test {
    protected:
        MyTestFixture() : sbuf{nullptr} {
            // intentionally empty
        }

        ~MyTestFixture() override = default;

        // Called before each unit test
        void SetUp() override {
            // Save cout's buffer...
            sbuf = std::cout.rdbuf();
            // Redirect cout to our stringstream buffer or any other ostream
            std::cout.rdbuf(buffer.rdbuf());
        }

        // Called after each unit test
        void TearDown() override {
            // When done redirect cout to its old self
            std::cout.rdbuf(sbuf);
            sbuf = nullptr;
        }

        // The following objects can be reused in each unit test

        // This can be an ofstream as well or any other ostream
        std::stringstream buffer{};
        // Save cout's buffer here
        std::streambuf *sbuf;
    };

    TEST_F(MyTestFixture, StackOverflowTest) {
        std::string expected{"Hello"};
        // Use cout as usual
        std::cout << expected;
        std::string actual{buffer.str()};
        EXPECT_EQ(expected, actual);
    }
} // end namespace
```

Comment: Just use a default member initializer for `sbuf` and you won't need the constructor and destructor. `std::streambuf *sbuf{}`

Answer (score 0):

Based on the answer of Wgaffa I made this helper class which can be constructed with either `std::cout` or `std::cerr`:

```
class CaptureHelper
{
public:
  CaptureHelper(std::ostream& ioStream)
    : mStream(ioStream),
    mIsCapturing(false)
  { }

  ~CaptureHelper()
  {
    release();
  }

  void capture()
  {
    if (!mIsCapturing)
    {
      mOriginalBuffer = mStream.rdbuf();
      mStream.rdbuf(mRedirectStream.rdbuf());
      mIsCapturing = true;
    }
  }

  std::string release()
  {
    if (mIsCapturing)
    {
      std::string wOutput = mRedirectStream.str();
      mStream.rdbuf(mOriginalBuffer);
      mIsCapturing = false;
      return wOutput;
    }
  }

private:
  std::ostream& mStream;
  bool mIsCapturing;
  std::stringstream mRedirectStream;
  std::streambuf* mOriginalBuffer;

};
```

Answer (score -1):

We are doing exactly what you are referring to.

First we created some macros:

```
    #define CAPTURE_STDOUT StdoutRedirect::instance().redirect();
    #define RELEASE_STDOUT StdoutRedirect::instance().reset();
    #define ASSERT_INFO( COUNT, TARGET )   \
      ASSERT_PRED_FORMAT2(OurTestPredicates::AssertInfoMsgOutput, TARGET, COUNT );
```

See this answer for capturing stdout and stderr:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/5419409/9796918
Just use their BeginCapture(), EndCapture() in place of our redirect() and reset().

In the AssertInfoMsgOutput method:

```
    AssertionResult OurTestPredicates::AssertInfoMsgOutput( const char* TARGET,
        const char* d1,
        const char* d2,
        int         COUNT )
    {
      int count = 0;
      bool match = false;
      std::string StdOutMessagge = GetCapture();
      // Here is where you process the stdout/stderr info for the TARGET, and for
      // COUNT instances of that TARGET message, and set count and match
      // appropriately
      ...
      if (( count == COUNT ) && match )
      {
        return ::testing::AssertionSuccess();
      }
      return :: testing::AssertionFailure() << "not found";
    }
```

Now in your unit test just wrap your calls that you want to capture stdout/stderr with:

```
    CAPTURE_STDOUT
    // Make your call to your code to test / capture here
    ASSERT_INFO( 1, "Foo bar" );
    RELEASE_STDOUT
```