# Is there a way to redirect stdout/stderr to a string?

Tags: c++, c, stdout, stderr

there has been many previous questions about redirecting  stdout/stderr to a file. is there a way to redirect  stdout/stderr to a string?

Answer (score 75, accepted):

Yes, you can redirect it to an `std::stringstream`:

```
std::stringstream buffer;
std::streambuf * old = std::cout.rdbuf(buffer.rdbuf());

std::cout << "Bla" << std::endl;

std::string text = buffer.str(); // text will now contain "Bla\n"
```

You can use a simple guard class to make sure the buffer is always reset:

```
struct cout_redirect {
    cout_redirect( std::streambuf * new_buffer ) 
        : old( std::cout.rdbuf( new_buffer ) )
    { }

    ~cout_redirect( ) {
        std::cout.rdbuf( old );
    }

private:
    std::streambuf * old;
};
```

Comment: that is for stdout. what about stderr?? do i have to redirect cerr?

Comment: Yes, you just do the same, but with `std::cerr`.

Comment: Sorry, my `C` (or `C++` for that matter) is a bit rusty, but that doesn't help when other parts of the application do `fprintf(stderr, ...)` or `fprintf(stdout, ...)` or `printf()`, doesn't it? Also, it doesn't help with `write(1, ...)` or `write(2, ...)`, even though that wasn't asked :-)

Comment: @Christian: No, it doesn't. This solution only works with C++ iostreams.

Comment: after yout first piece of code cout is disabled. it prints nothing.

Comment: @MinimusHeximus: That is the point - the output is redirected into a string, not to the screen. To print to the screen again, you have to restore the original buffer to `cout`.

Comment: That struct is nice, do you know of a way to make this work for printf too for the entire application?

Comment: Unfortunately no, I don't think that is possible.

Comment: @Gizmo i think this *unholy abomination*  should work for printf and system() and just about everything, on linux anyway.. https://wandbox.org/permlink/okEe7xDW4ZtaJZtO - it works by duplicating stdout, then closing stdout, then creating a tmpfile() and hoping it will get id 1/become the new stdout...

Answer (score 46):

You can use this class:

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string>

class StdCapture
{
public:
    StdCapture(): m_capturing(false), m_init(false), m_oldStdOut(0), m_oldStdErr(0)
    {
        m_pipe[READ] = 0;
        m_pipe[WRITE] = 0;
        if (_pipe(m_pipe, 65536, O_BINARY) == -1)
            return;
        m_oldStdOut = dup(fileno(stdout));
        m_oldStdErr = dup(fileno(stderr));
        if (m_oldStdOut == -1 || m_oldStdErr == -1)
            return;

        m_init = true;
    }

    ~StdCapture()
    {
        if (m_capturing)
        {
            EndCapture();
        }
        if (m_oldStdOut > 0)
            close(m_oldStdOut);
        if (m_oldStdErr > 0)
            close(m_oldStdErr);
        if (m_pipe[READ] > 0)
            close(m_pipe[READ]);
        if (m_pipe[WRITE] > 0)
            close(m_pipe[WRITE]);
    }


    void BeginCapture()
    {
        if (!m_init)
            return;
        if (m_capturing)
            EndCapture();
        fflush(stdout);
        fflush(stderr);
        dup2(m_pipe[WRITE], fileno(stdout));
        dup2(m_pipe[WRITE], fileno(stderr));
        m_capturing = true;
    }

    bool EndCapture()
    {
        if (!m_init)
            return false;
        if (!m_capturing)
            return false;
        fflush(stdout);
        fflush(stderr);
        dup2(m_oldStdOut, fileno(stdout));
        dup2(m_oldStdErr, fileno(stderr));
        m_captured.clear();

        std::string buf;
        const int bufSize = 1024;
        buf.resize(bufSize);
        int bytesRead = 0;
        if (!eof(m_pipe[READ]))
        {
            bytesRead = read(m_pipe[READ], &(*buf.begin()), bufSize);
        }
        while(bytesRead == bufSize)
        {
            m_captured += buf;
            bytesRead = 0;
            if (!eof(m_pipe[READ]))
            {
                bytesRead = read(m_pipe[READ], &(*buf.begin()), bufSize);
            }
        }
        if (bytesRead > 0)
        {
            buf.resize(bytesRead);
            m_captured += buf;
        }
        m_capturing = false;
        return true;
    }

    std::string GetCapture() const
    {
        std::string::size_type idx = m_captured.find_last_not_of("\r\n");
        if (idx == std::string::npos)
        {
            return m_captured;
        }
        else
        {
            return m_captured.substr(0, idx+1);
        }
    }

private:
    enum PIPES { READ, WRITE };
    int m_pipe[2];
    int m_oldStdOut;
    int m_oldStdErr;
    bool m_capturing;
    bool m_init;
    std::string m_captured;
};
```

call `BeginCapture()` when you need to start capture
call `EndCapture()` when you need to stop capture
call `GetCapture()` to retrieve captured output

Comment: I am not too familiar with pipes, but how large is a pipe's buffer in the kernel? In other words, how many bytes can you pass to write() w/o calling read() before write() blocks?

Comment: +1 for a *reallY* complicated solution to a trivial problem! :)

Comment: @Nim: I used this class by myself, because Borland Builder 4 (where I needed such redirect) had fatal bug in std::stringstream. For normal compilers solution of Space_C0wb0y is more appropriate :)

Comment: +1 for a solution that handles all stdout/stderr (unlike the accepted solution which only does cout/cerr).

Comment: O_BINARY and some other identifiers are unkownn to my compiler.

Comment: @MinimusHeximus: This is written for MSVC compilers, I believe. The _pipe() function is documented in MSDN.

Comment: It does though use `unistd.h`, which implies POSIX.  `_pipe` conventionally would be the"real syscall" wrapped by `pipe()` from `unistd.h`.

Answer (score 20):

In order to provide a thread-safe & cross platform solution, I have adapted rmflow's approach into a similar interface. As this class modifies global file descriptors, I adapted it to a mutex-guarded static class that protects against multiple instances thrashing global file descriptors. In addition, rmflow's answer does not clean up all of the used file descriptors which can lead to problems opening new ones (for output streams or files) if many BeginCapture() & EndCapture() calls are used in one application. This code has been tested on Windows 7/8, Linux, OSX, Android, and iOS.

**NOTE:** In order to use std::mutex you must compile against c++ 11. If you do not / cannot use c++11, you can remove the mutex calls completely (sacrificing thread safety) or you can find a legacy sychronization mechanism to get the job done.

```
#ifdef _MSC_VER
#include <io.h>
#define popen _popen 
#define pclose _pclose
#define stat _stat 
#define dup _dup
#define dup2 _dup2
#define fileno _fileno
#define close _close
#define pipe _pipe
#define read _read
#define eof _eof
#else
#include <unistd.h>
#endif
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <mutex>

class StdCapture
{
public:
    static void Init()
    {
        // make stdout & stderr streams unbuffered
        // so that we don't need to flush the streams
        // before capture and after capture 
        // (fflush can cause a deadlock if the stream is currently being 
        std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(m_mutex);
        setvbuf(stdout,NULL,_IONBF,0);
        setvbuf(stderr,NULL,_IONBF,0);
    }

    static void BeginCapture()
    {
        std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(m_mutex);
        if (m_capturing)
            return;

        secure_pipe(m_pipe);
        m_oldStdOut = secure_dup(STD_OUT_FD);
        m_oldStdErr = secure_dup(STD_ERR_FD);
        secure_dup2(m_pipe[WRITE],STD_OUT_FD);
        secure_dup2(m_pipe[WRITE],STD_ERR_FD);
        m_capturing = true;
#ifndef _MSC_VER
        secure_close(m_pipe[WRITE]);
#endif
    }
    static bool IsCapturing()
    {
        std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(m_mutex);
        return m_capturing;
    }
    static bool EndCapture()
    {
        std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(m_mutex);
        if (!m_capturing)
            return;

        m_captured.clear();
        secure_dup2(m_oldStdOut, STD_OUT_FD);
        secure_dup2(m_oldStdErr, STD_ERR_FD);

        const int bufSize = 1025;
        char buf[bufSize];
        int bytesRead = 0;
        bool fd_blocked(false);
        do
        {
            bytesRead = 0;
            fd_blocked = false;
#ifdef _MSC_VER
            if (!eof(m_pipe[READ]))
                bytesRead = read(m_pipe[READ], buf, bufSize-1);
#else
            bytesRead = read(m_pipe[READ], buf, bufSize-1);
#endif
            if (bytesRead > 0)
            {
                buf[bytesRead] = 0;
                m_captured += buf;
            }
            else if (bytesRead < 0)
            {
                fd_blocked = (errno == EAGAIN || errno == EWOULDBLOCK || errno == EINTR);
                if (fd_blocked)
                    std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(10));
            }
        }
        while(fd_blocked || bytesRead == (bufSize-1));

        secure_close(m_oldStdOut);
        secure_close(m_oldStdErr);
        secure_close(m_pipe[READ]);
#ifdef _MSC_VER
        secure_close(m_pipe[WRITE]);
#endif
        m_capturing = false;
    }
    static std::string GetCapture()
    {
        std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(m_mutex);
        return m_captured;
    }
private:
    enum PIPES { READ, WRITE };

    int StdCapture::secure_dup(int src)
    {
        int ret = -1;
        bool fd_blocked = false;
        do
        {
             ret = dup(src);
             fd_blocked = (errno == EINTR ||  errno == EBUSY);
             if (fd_blocked)
                std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(10));
        }
        while (ret < 0);
        return ret;
    }
    void StdCapture::secure_pipe(int * pipes)
    {
        int ret = -1;
        bool fd_blocked = false;
        do
        {
#ifdef _MSC_VER
            ret = pipe(pipes, 65536, O_BINARY);
#else
            ret = pipe(pipes) == -1;
#endif
            fd_blocked = (errno == EINTR ||  errno == EBUSY);
            if (fd_blocked)
                std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(10));
        }
        while (ret < 0);
    }
    void StdCapture::secure_dup2(int src, int dest)
    {
        int ret = -1;
        bool fd_blocked = false;
        do
        {
             ret = dup2(src,dest);
             fd_blocked = (errno == EINTR ||  errno == EBUSY);
             if (fd_blocked)
                std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(10));
        }
        while (ret < 0);
    }

    void StdCapture::secure_close(int & fd)
    {
        int ret = -1;
        bool fd_blocked = false;
        do
        {
             ret = close(fd);
             fd_blocked = (errno == EINTR);
             if (fd_blocked)
                std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(10));
        }
        while (ret < 0);

        fd = -1;
    }

    static int m_pipe[2];
    static int m_oldStdOut;
    static int m_oldStdErr;
    static bool m_capturing;
    static std::mutex m_mutex;
    static std::string m_captured;
};

// actually define vars.
int StdCapture::m_pipe[2];
int StdCapture::m_oldStdOut;
int StdCapture::m_oldStdErr;
bool StdCapture::m_capturing;
std::mutex StdCapture::m_mutex;
std::string StdCapture::m_captured;
```

call `Init()` once (before capture) to remove buffering to stdout / stderr

call `BeginCapture()` when you need to start capture

call `EndCapture()` when you need to stop capture

call `GetCapture()` to retrieve captured output

call `IsCapturing()` to see if stdout/stderr is currently redirected

Comment: The code listed in this answer is absolutely free to use by whomever wants to. I can attach a BSD liscense if necessary.

Comment: Digby. Cool! Can you comment to that meta thread to that effect? The OP there doesn't have sufficient rep to engage here yet.

Comment: Done. I can attach a license tomorrow when I get in reach of a desktop  PC.

Comment: this does not even compile - missing headers (`chrono`, `thread`) to start with ...

Comment: To be specific this code only works for Windows Console apps. For a Windows GUI apps there's more work to do.

Comment: This fails to compile for me in Ubuntu with C++11 due to extra qualifications on declarations, STD_OUT_FD and such not being declared in scope, and std::this_thread not being declared. Does anyone know how to fix these?

Comment: What I did is: ` #ifndef STD_OUT_FD
#define STD_OUT_FD (fileno(stdout))
#endif
#ifndef STD_ERR_FD
#define STD_ERR_FD (fileno(stderr))
#endif
`

Comment: Ouch. This code is flawed in many ways. Firstly, the thinking behind thread-safety is flawed. Secondly, the odd mixture of static data members and nonstatic member functions doesn't work. Thirdly, it fails to compile due to undefined symbols. Fourth, there is no need to switch off buffering at the beginning, it would be sufficient to flush the buffers, plus there is no code to switch buffering back on after stopping the capturing. Fifth is the way the captured data is handled: m_captured is cleared only when ending the capture, rather than by GetCapture(), which would be the obvious place.

Comment: @konserw you might find a header called `<unistd.h>` which includes `STDIN_FILENO`, `STDOUT_FILENO` AND `STDERR_FILENO`. It's a POSIX standard header, so should be present on all modern *nix-alike systems.

Answer (score 6):

i've furnished a qt osx ready variation from Björn Pollex code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <streambuf>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>

class CoutRedirect {

public:
    CoutRedirect() {
        old = std::cout.rdbuf( buffer.rdbuf() ); // redirect cout to buffer stream
    }

    std::string getString() {
        return buffer.str(); // get string
    }

    ~CoutRedirect( ) {
        std::cout.rdbuf( old ); // reverse redirect
    }

private:
    std::stringstream buffer;
    std::streambuf * old;
};
```

Answer (score 6):

I modified class from `Sir Digby Chicken Caesar` so that it's not static and could be used easily in unit tests. It works for me on Windows compiled by gcc (g++), but I cannot guarantee that it is 100% correct, please leave comments if it is not.

Create object of class StdCapture, and just call `BeginCapture()` to begin capture and `EndCapture()` at the end. Code from `Init()` is moved to the constructor. There shall be only one such object working at a time.

StdCapture.h:

```
#ifdef _MSC_VER
#include <io.h>
#define popen _popen 
#define pclose _pclose
#define stat _stat 
#define dup _dup
#define dup2 _dup2
#define fileno _fileno
#define close _close
#define pipe _pipe
#define read _read
#define eof _eof
#else
#include <unistd.h>
#endif
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <mutex>
#include <chrono>
#include <thread>

#ifndef STD_OUT_FD 
#define STD_OUT_FD (fileno(stdout)) 
#endif 

#ifndef STD_ERR_FD 
#define STD_ERR_FD (fileno(stderr)) 
#endif

class StdCapture
{
public:

    StdCapture();

    void BeginCapture();
    bool IsCapturing();
    bool EndCapture();
    std::string GetCapture();

private:
    enum PIPES { READ, WRITE };
    
    int secure_dup(int src);
    void secure_pipe(int * pipes);
    void secure_dup2(int src, int dest);
    void secure_close(int & fd);

    int m_pipe[2];
    int m_oldStdOut;
    int m_oldStdErr;
    bool m_capturing;
    std::mutex m_mutex;
    std::string m_captured;
};
```

StdCapture.cpp:

```
#include "StdCapture.h"

StdCapture::StdCapture():
    m_capturing(false)
{
    // make stdout & stderr streams unbuffered
    // so that we don't need to flush the streams
    // before capture and after capture 
    // (fflush can cause a deadlock if the stream is currently being 
    std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(m_mutex);
    setvbuf(stdout,NULL,_IONBF,0);
    setvbuf(stderr,NULL,_IONBF,0);
}

void StdCapture::BeginCapture()
{
    std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(m_mutex);
    if (m_capturing)
        return;

    secure_pipe(m_pipe);
    m_oldStdOut = secure_dup(STD_OUT_FD);
    m_oldStdErr = secure_dup(STD_ERR_FD);
    secure_dup2(m_pipe[WRITE],STD_OUT_FD);
    secure_dup2(m_pipe[WRITE],STD_ERR_FD);
    m_capturing = true;
#ifndef _MSC_VER
    secure_close(m_pipe[WRITE]);
#endif
}
bool StdCapture::IsCapturing()
{
    std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(m_mutex);
    return m_capturing;
}
bool StdCapture::EndCapture()
{
    std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(m_mutex);
    if (!m_capturing)
        return true;

    m_captured.clear();
    secure_dup2(m_oldStdOut, STD_OUT_FD);
    secure_dup2(m_oldStdErr, STD_ERR_FD);

    const int bufSize = 1025;
    char buf[bufSize];
    int bytesRead = 0;
    bool fd_blocked(false);
    do
    {
        bytesRead = 0;
        fd_blocked = false;
#ifdef _MSC_VER
        if (!eof(m_pipe[READ]))
            bytesRead = read(m_pipe[READ], buf, bufSize-1);
#else
        bytesRead = read(m_pipe[READ], buf, bufSize-1);
#endif
        if (bytesRead > 0)
        {
            buf[bytesRead] = 0;
            m_captured += buf;
        }
        else if (bytesRead < 0)
        {
            fd_blocked = (errno == EAGAIN || errno == EWOULDBLOCK || errno == EINTR);
            if (fd_blocked)
                std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(10));
        }
    }
    while(fd_blocked || bytesRead == (bufSize-1));

    secure_close(m_oldStdOut);
    secure_close(m_oldStdErr);
    secure_close(m_pipe[READ]);
#ifdef _MSC_VER
    secure_close(m_pipe[WRITE]);
#endif
    m_capturing = false;
    return true;
}
std::string StdCapture::GetCapture()
{
    std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(m_mutex);
    return m_captured;
}

int StdCapture::secure_dup(int src)
{
    int ret = -1;
    bool fd_blocked = false;
    do
    {
         ret = dup(src);
         fd_blocked = (errno == EINTR ||  errno == EBUSY);
         if (fd_blocked)
            std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(10));
    }
    while (ret < 0);
    return ret;
}
void StdCapture::secure_pipe(int * pipes)
{
    int ret = -1;
    bool fd_blocked = false;
    do
    {
#ifdef _MSC_VER
        ret = pipe(pipes, 65536, O_BINARY);
#else
        ret = pipe(pipes) == -1;
#endif
        fd_blocked = (errno == EINTR ||  errno == EBUSY);
        if (fd_blocked)
            std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(10));
    }
    while (ret < 0);
}
void StdCapture::secure_dup2(int src, int dest)
{
    int ret = -1;
    bool fd_blocked = false;
    do
    {
         ret = dup2(src,dest);
         fd_blocked = (errno == EINTR ||  errno == EBUSY);
         if (fd_blocked)
            std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(10));
    }
    while (ret < 0);
}

void StdCapture::secure_close(int & fd)
{
    int ret = -1;
    bool fd_blocked = false;
    do
    {
         ret = close(fd);
         fd_blocked = (errno == EINTR);
         if (fd_blocked)
            std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(10));
    }
    while (ret < 0);

    fd = -1;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for cleaning up the code. FWIW, I took it to GitHub, crediting you and the other authors: https://github.com/dmikushin/stdcapture

Comment: I tried to use @Dmitry Mikushin 's solution, it compiles but freezes, any idea ?

Comment: @AlGrenadine, hey what do you compile, which OS? Please open an issue on github, if it applies there.

Answer (score 4):

Since your question is tagged C as well as C++, it seems appropriate to mention that although you cannot associate a string to a FILE * in standard C, there are several non-standard libraries that allow that.  glibc is almost standard, so you may be perfectly happy using fmemopen()  See http://www.gnu.org/s/libc/manual/html_mono/libc.html#String-Streams

Comment: No need; just reassign `stderr`, as in `stderr = open_memstream(...);`.

Comment: Note: you need to `fclose` the original `stderr` and also need to handle errors.

Comment: stderr can't be used as lvalue for assignment. Its a #define.