# When std::cout is called what external API is used? (Windows)

Tags: c++, reverse-engineering

This is a *reverse engineering* question.

On Windows 7 with a binary compiled using Microsoft Visual C++ 2008, when `std::cout` is called. Internally, **what API is used to write the data**? WriteFile, fwrite, ConsoleOut? I am aiming to set a breakpoint on std::cout where no source or debugging symbols are available.

Comment: You may want to try to redirect `std::cout` into an `std::stringstream` instead. This is very suitable for debugging. Check [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5419356/) for info on how to do it.

Comment: @Space_C0wb0y the binary in question is machine code. There is no such thing as std::cout or std::stringstream at this point. This is a hacking / reversing question.

Comment: Just use the debugger to walk through the process of outputting a single character. Should be very informative. Edit: Use the debugger on a test program to learn about the underlying process, of course.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe it'll end up using WriteFile. It you compile a simple `hello world`:

```
#include <iostream>
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
  std::cout << "Hello" << std::endl;
  return (0);
}
```

...and then do `dumpbin /imports hello.exe`, you get a list of the external functions it uses, you'll find that it imports both `WriteFile` and `WriteConsoleW`, but if memory serves, the latter is only used for printing some standard library error messages, not for standard output.

Comment: Wow, this is horrible. It looks as if it is writing out a byte at a time!

Comment: @MSalters no. I did find out that WriteFile was called however.