# Overload cout operator to work as outttextxy

Tags: c++, bgi

There is a possibility to overload << operator in C++ to as the function outtextxy from graphics.h ?

For example:

`cout<<"This is an example";`

I would it working like:

`outtextxy(100, 100, "This is an example");`

Comment: There might be but do note that `graphics.h` is very old and does not work with pretty much all modern compilers.  Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7860569/how-i-can-get-and-use-the-header-file-graphics-h-in-my-c-program

Comment: Also related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5419356/redirect-stdout-stderr-to-a-string