# Why does this RAII cout redirector not work:

Tags: c++, iostream

I wanted to use the approach given in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/5419388/2050788, but apparently I'm missing something, as cout does not wind up being redirected.  Can someone explain what I'm missing?

Here's a minimal compileable example:

```
#include <sstream>
#include <streambuf>
#include <iostream>

struct cout_redirect {
    cout_redirect( std::streambuf * new_buffer )
        : old( std::cout.rdbuf( new_buffer ) )
    { }

    ~cout_redirect( ) {
        std::cout.rdbuf( old );
    }

private:
    std::streambuf * old;
};

void no_guard() {
  std::cout << "No RAII" << std::endl;
  std::stringstream buffer;
  std::streambuf *old = std::cout.rdbuf(buffer.rdbuf());
  std::cout << "Bla" << std::endl;
  std::cout.rdbuf(old);
  std::cout << "Text = " << buffer.str() << std::endl;
}

void with_guard()
{
  std::cout << "Using RAII" << std::endl;
  std::stringstream buffer;
  cout_redirect(buffer.rdbuf());
  std::cout << "Bla";
}

int main() {
  no_guard();
  with_guard();
}
```

The output is:

```
 No RAII 
 Text = Bla

 Using RAII
 Bla
```

The No RAII case works as expected.  In the RAII case, I would expect there to be no output, as cout should be redirected to the stringstream buffer.  What am I missing?  (compiled with `g++ -Wall test.cpp` using gcc 7.3.1).

EDIT:  Ok, I was being really dumb -- but I'm big enough to admit it and leave this here as a reminder of my fallibility.

Comment: Note also that you should probably delete copy constructor of `cout_redirect `. Rule of 3/5/0...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that `cout_redirect(buffer.rdbuf());` just creates temporary object that is deleted on `;`. Try `cout_redirect cr(buffer.rdbuf());`.

In practice it's nice to wrap such thing in macro to generate unique name automatically.

Answer (score 0):

`cout_redirect(buffer.rdbuf());` constructs a temporary `cout_redirect` object, which redirects `cout`, then destroys the temporary object, which restores `cout`.

Did you mean `cout_redirect guard(buffer.rdbuf());` instead?

Comment: @Spacemoose Side note: You could've reduced your test case much more by removing all cout redirection and just printing debug messages in your constructor/destructor. :-)

Comment: yeah... what can I say.  I'm having a bad day.