# How to redirect stdout and stderr streams (Multiplatform)?

Tags: c++, console-application, stdout, stderr, multiplatform

I'm writing GL application that uses external libs, which print errors to the console. I want to catch that and print in the in-game console.

PS: Sorry, for my bad english....

Comment: http://homepage.ntlworld.com/jonathan.deboynepollard/FGA/redirecting-standard-io.html

Answer (score 4):

There are two basic approaches you could take to this:

1. If the libraries all use `std::cout` for the IO you want to capture you can [write your own `basic_streambuf`](http://spec.winprog.org/streams/). You can then just call `std::cout.rdbuf(mybufinst);` to replace the streambuffer, for example using the `std::basic_stringbuf`:

   ```
   #include <sstream>
   #include <iostream>

   int main() {
      static std::basic_stringbuf<std::ostream::char_type> buf;
      std::cout.rdbuf(&buf);
      std::cout << "Hello captured world!\n";
      std::cerr << "Stole: " << buf.str() << std::endl;
   }
   ```
2. You can use a platform specific approach, e.g. on POSIX systems [`dup2()` will allow you to replace a file descriptor with another one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3803465/how-to-capture-stdout-stderr-with-googletest/4031916#4031916), or on Windows with [`SetStdHandle()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686244%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). You'd want to use pipes rather than just another file probably and you'd need to be really careful about blocking (so probably want a dedicated thread)