# How to capture output of printf?

Tags: c++, c, printf

I am calling a function `funcB` from `funcA`.
`funcB` uses several `printf` statements to output data.
Is there a way for me to capture that data via `funcA`?
I can not modify `funcB`.

```
funcB(){
     printf( "%s", "My Name is" );
     printf( "%s", "I like ice cream" );
}

funcA(){
    funcB();
}
```

Comment: What if `funcB` wouldn't print its output, but return it to `funcA` instead? Hard to say from abstract description as you provided, be more specific.

Comment: *"This is a C++ question"* - it looks more like a C question to me. If it were C++ you could do something like: [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8076948/168175).

Comment: It looks more like an OS-specfic question to me, as alluded to in my answer.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

(This answer is a corrected version based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4832902/315052).)

This answer is POSIX centric. Use `open` to create a file descriptor for the file you want to redirect to. Then, use `dup2` to `STDOUT_FILENO` to change `stdout` to write to the file instead. But, you'll want to `dup` the `STDOUT_FILENO` before you do that, so you can restore `stdout` with another `dup2`.

```
fflush(stdout);
int stdout_fd = dup(STDOUT_FILENO);
int redir_fd = open(redirected_filename, O_WRONLY);
dup2(redir_fd, STDOUT_FILENO);
close(redir_fd);
funcB();
fflush(stdout);
dup2(stdout_fd, STDOUT_FILENO);
close(stdout_fd);
```

If `funcB` is using `std::cout`, use `std::cout.flush()` instead of `fflush(stdout)`.

If you want to manipulate C++ streams more directly, you can use [Johnathan Wakely's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10940765/redirecting-stdout-from-another-program-in-c/).

Comment: How to revert stdout once again to the screen?

Comment: I appended `cout << "should go" <<endl;
  printf("to normal again\n");` after `close(stdout_fd);` but I don't see this output on the screen, neither in "redirected_filename.txt".

Comment: @Viesturs You might need to adjust line flushing discipline, but the output should exist if you manually flush it. If not, I expect the code you are testing messed something up.

Comment: How to do the line flushing?

Comment: `fflush(stdout)` and `cout.flush()`.

Comment: That didn't help

Comment: @Viesturs: Like I said, I expect the code you are testing messed something up. Consider posting a new question.

Comment: I am banned to ask questions here.

Comment: @jxh: I'm having the same trouble @Viesturs was.  Despite using proper flushing, `stdout` is not restored for me, and printing to it doesn't go to the console or the redirected file.  gcc 8.3.0 (or 6.5.0) and glibc 2.29.  As you asked him to do, posted a new question here: (with full code) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56097917/restoring-stdout-after-redirecting-it-via-freopen

Comment: @user1902689: Thanks for that. R.'s answer was very enlightening to me.

Answer (score 2):

If nothing else in your program uses `printf`, you can write your own version and link it explicitly. The linker will not look in the standard library if the function is already defined. You can probably use [`vsprintf`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdio/vsprintf/) for the implementation, or some safer version with overrun checking if it is supplied by your compiler.

Answer (score 1):

If you're willing to play a dirty game interposing on `printf` you can 'steal' its output doing something like:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdarg.h>

static char buffer[1024];
static char *next = buffer;

static void funcB(){
     printf( "%s", "My Name is" );
     printf( "%s", "I like ice cream" );
}

static void funcA(){
    funcB();
    // Do stuff iwth buffer here
    fprintf(stderr, "stole: %s\n", buffer);
    next=buffer; // reset for later.
}

int main() {
  funcA();
}


int printf(const char *fmt, ...) {
   va_list argp;
   va_start(argp, fmt);
   const int ret = vsnprintf(next, sizeof buffer-(next-buffer), fmt, argp);
   next += ret;
   va_end(argp);
   return ret;
}
```

You could use a flag to indicate how to handle the instances where you want printf to work as normal. (E.g. map it onto `fprintf` or use `dlsym()`/similar to find the real call).

You could also use `realloc` to manage the size of the buffer more sensibly.

Answer (score 0):

Put `funcB` in a separate program. You can then capture its standard output, e.g. by piping or by redirecting it to a file. How to do that generally depends on the OS and is outside the realm of C++.

Alternatively, maybe you can redirect your `funcA` process' standard output to a file, then call `FuncB`, and retrieve the output from the file.

Again, how to do that is outside the realm of C++ and depends on the OS.