Redirect stdout in unit testing with ctest
Writing unit test with ctest. The function to test is doing printout to stdout/stderr.
So, right now, I am having:
typedef struct {
  char *stdout_file;
  char *stderr_file;
} test_config;

static int group_setup(void **state) {
  test_config *tc = malloc(sizeof(test_config));
  tc->stdout_file = strdup("/tmp/new_stdout.txt");
  tc->stderr_file = strdup("/tmp/new_stderr.txt");
  *state = tc;
  return 0;
}

static int setup(void **state) {
  test_config *tc = *state;
  if(!freopen(tc->stdout_file, "a+", stdout)) {
     fprintf(stderr, "redirection failed to %s: %m", tc->stdout_file);
     return -1;
  }
  if(!freopen(tc->stderr_file, "a+", stderr)) {
     fprintf(stderr, "redirection failed to %s: %m", tc->stderr_file);
     return -1;
  }
  return 0;
}

static int teardown(void **state) {
  test_config *tc = *state;
  /// How to restore stdout???
  return 0;
}

static int group_teardown(void **state) {
  test_config *tc = *state;
  free(tc->stdout_file);
  free(tc->stderr_file);
  free(tc);
  return 0;
}

static void test(void **state) {
   function_to_test(); // it should always print something to stdout or stderr

   char buffer[LINE_MAX];
   FILE *out = fopen(tc->stdout_file, "r");
   fread(buffer, 1, sizeof(buffer), out);
   fclose(out);

   int rc = memcmp(buffer, expected_output, strlen(expected_output));
   assert_int_equal(rc, 0);
}

int main() {
  const struct CMUnitTest tests[] = {
    cmocka_unit_test_setup_teardown(test, setup, teardown),
  }
  return cmocka_run_group_tests(tests, group_setup, group_teardown);
}

The issue I have is that the file used for redirection is not created. But message from freopen() failure is not printed. In the LastTest.log I see:
[ RUN ] mytest
<end of output>

Which leads me to believe that the redirection actually happened. But where are the files?
And how can I return stdout/stderr back to ctest? Why do not I see [ PASSED ] mytest in the test log?
Is there a better way to do it? Should not ctest already have some built-in ability to check contents of stdout? It is fairly common issue, isn't it?

Does it have to use freopen()? https://stackoverflow.com/q/11110300/315052

See How to redirect output back to the screen after freopen("out.txt", "a", stdout)?

@JonathanLeffler No, sorry. In my case, the output is already redirected by ctest to LastTest.log. I really need to "restore" it. Not to redirect to actual console.

You will have to work out where it was going before ctest redirected it.  That probably means you'll have to take charge before ctest runs.  I've no knowledge of ctest specifically, but check the manuals to see whether there is a way to do it within the test infrastructure.  Also, reconsider why you need to do it.  Are you sure reinstating stdout is truly necessary?

The %m format specification is non-standard (as in, neither Standard C nor POSIX), but is a feature of the GNU C Library.  Have you checked that the setup() function is called (by writing a message to stderr before you attempt any redirection)?  Have you checked that the test_config structure in setup contains the names you expect?  Is the group_setup() function called before the setup() function?  Have you considered catching the old value of stdout in there?  Can you tell via fstat() whether standard output is connected to your terminal when group_setup() is called?

you might try fclose() and fopen().  I was surprised that fclose() worked on stdout and such, but it does.  Not advising this actually, because the community may feel this is UB.

But why not just use ctest? You are already using it. Use https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/prop_test/PASS_REGULAR_EXPRESSION.html

Finally, I solved the issue like this:
static int setup(void **state) {
   test_config *tc = *state;
   // nothing to do with capturing TTY
   return 0;
}

static int teardown(void **state) {
   test_config *tc = *state;
   unlink(tc->stdout_file);
   unlink(tc->stderr_file);
   return 0;
}

static void capture_tty(void **state) {
   test_config *tc = *state;
   fflush(stdout);
   tc->stdout_fd = dup(STDOUT_FILENO);
   int redir_fd = open(tc->stdout_file, O_WRONLY | O_CREAT, S_IREAD | S_IWRITE);
   dup2(redir_fd, STDOUT_FILENO);
   close(redir_fd);
   // same for stderr
}

static void release_tty(void **state) {
   test_config *tc = *state;
   fflush(stdout);
   dup2(tc->stdout_fd, STDOUT_FILENO);
   close(tc->stdout_fd);
   // same for stderr
}

static void test(void **state) {
   capture_tty(state);
   function_to_test(); // it should always print something to stdout or stderr
   release_tty(state);

   // at this moment, standard streams are back under ctest's control and
   // all assert_*() work as expected.
}

That approach gives a full capture of stdout/stderr for just tested functions. While not interfering with ctest's own capture.
Thank you guys for the hints.
