# Capture thread dump in bash

Tags: c++, bash, opencv, io-redirection

My command fails with what I think is a thread dump or something. Since I want to inspect, I would like to redirect the output to a file or less. However the output doesn't seem to be on stderr or stdout?! How can I capture this output?

```
7f47efcda000-7f47efcdb000 r--p 00000000 fc:00 174138                     /usr/lib/libgtest_main.so.0.0.0
7f47efcdb000-7f47efcdc000 rw-p 00001000 fc:00 174138                     /usr/lib/libgtest_main.so.0.0.0
7f47efcdc000-7f47efd25000 r-xp 00000000 fc:00 174141                     /usr/lib/libgtest.so.0.0.0
7f47efd25000-7f47eff25000 ---p 00049000 fc:00 174141                     /usr/lib/libgtest.so.0.0.0
7f47eff25000-7f47eff26000 r--p 00049000 fc:00 174141                     /usr/lib/libgtest.so.0.0.0
7f47eff26000-7f47eff27000 rw-p 0004a000 fc:00 174141                     /usr/lib/libgtest.so.0.0.0
7f47eff27000-7f47eff28000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
7f47eff28000-7f47eff4e000 r-xp 00000000 fc:00 899                        /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-2.23.so
7f47f00c6000-7f47f00e2000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
7f47f00e2000-7f47f0100000 r-xp 00000000 fc:00 422                        /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libudev.so.1.6.4
7f47f0100000-7f47f0101000 r--p 0001d000 fc:00 422                        /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libudev.so.1.6.4
7f47f0101000-7f47f0102000 rw-p 0001e000 fc:00 422                        /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libudev.so.1.6.4
7f47f0102000-7f47f0132000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
7f47f014c000-7f47f014d000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
7f47f014d000-7f47f014e000 r--p 00025000 fc:00 899                        /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-2.23.so
7f47f014e000-7f47f014f000 rw-p 00026000 fc:00 899                        /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-2.23.so
7f47f014f000-7f47f0150000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
7ffca7f25000-7ffca7f46000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0                          [stack]
7ffca7f84000-7ffca7f86000 r--p 00000000 00:00 0                          [vvar]
7ffca7f86000-7ffca7f88000 r-xp 00000000 00:00 0                          [vdso]
ffffffffff600000-ffffffffff601000 r-xp 00000000 00:00 0                  [vsyscall]
2/2 Test #2: subscriberSkeleton_gtest .........***Exception: Other  0.03 sec

0% tests passed, 2 tests failed out of 2

Total Test time (real) =   0.07 sec
```

I tried variations of `make test 2> file`, `make test 2>&1 | less`, these only output the last lines, not the dump.

The code in question is just this:

```
#include <gtest/gtest.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    ::testing::InitGoogleTest(&argc, argv);
    return RUN_ALL_TESTS();
}
```

The issue that makes this program fail is that it is linked together with OpenCV, which contains a testing component opencv_ts that conflicts with GTest. [Blog post](https://schneide.wordpress.com/2014/02/03/testing-c-code-with-opencv-dependencies/) of someone with the same problem. I know how to solve this, but am stumped as to why I can't capture the output that is produced by the error.

Comment: What output is this from? and how did you attempt to capture this?

Comment: You are probably looking for redirection (i.e. "2> logfile"), for example: `command 2> error.log`.

Comment: @MichaWiedenmann I tried this but for some reason this does not capture the big block of the dump, just the "normal" output of the CTest program.

Comment: @Inian This output is coming from a segfault, the same problem as this guy: https://schneide.wordpress.com/2014/02/03/testing-c-code-with-opencv-dependencies/

Answer (score 2):

this is probably glibc producing output, for example when you have double-free()s. Setting the following environment variable may help: `LIBC_FATAL_STDERR_=1` (The output will then be in STDERR.)

However, with the output you pasted this could also be kernel output, which happens independently from your program.

Comment: Yes, this is indeed a double free problem.

Comment: Sorry, it's `LIBC_FATAL_STDERR_=1`, with a trailing underscore.

Comment: Ah yes, that does something. Now I don't see the output at all, but that might just be a mistake on my side.

Comment: `LIBC_FATAL_STDERR_=1 ./double_free 2>&1 | less` seems to work for me (where double_free is a program that does a double-free())

Comment: Veeeery odd but if `LIBC_FATAL_STDERR_` is undefined the output shows but can't be captured, when it is defined the output does not show at all (but the program is still broken).

Comment: Does it work with a smaller test case?
double_free.c
#include <stdio.h>

    int main() {
            char *foo = malloc(10);
            free(foo);
            free(foo);
    }

Comment: Hmm... Maybe you could share some of the surrounding bash code or try planting in the double_free program instead.

Comment: I don't know, maybe this isn't double-free after all. The problem is described here: https://schneide.wordpress.com/2014/02/03/testing-c-code-with-opencv-dependencies/     Would a segfault produce output like I showed?

Comment: Okay, looks like it's something to do with gtest. I googled for 'gtest capture stdout' and hit on e.g.: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3803465/how-to-capture-stdout-stderr-with-googletest
I don't know how gtest works, but setting LIBC_FATAL_STDERR_=1 possibly prevents gtest from getting the glibc output. (There are other ways to get at this output)